# object modified event FabricJS (I-Text background color)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, fabricjs

Is there a way to tell (immediately) when an I-Text "textBackgroundColor" is modified ?

This is my code but it only catches movement events or scales and so on, not I-Text 'fill' or 'textBackgroundColor'...

```
canvas.on('object:modified', function(e) {
   console.log('modification occurred')
   if (e.target.get('type') == 'i-text') {
       if (e.target.get('textBackgroundColor').length > 0) {
           console.log('background color exists');
       }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

No it won't fire `object:modified` for property change. You can use `canvas.fire('object:modified',{ target: object })` to manually fire event while setting property to the object.